Can anyone who uses VsCode can help me with this problem? its version 1.96.2
i have been trying to fix this dropdown box problem but nothing worked. i want someone who knows all the in's and outs of vscode to help me out in this. this is running on windows.
i tried disabling/reinstalling all the themes i have downloaded. i tried disabling all the code runners and autocompletion extensions, yet nothing happened.

How to ask has a chapter about "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem", please read that....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/79293790/11107541

I was able to reproduce your problem by tinkering the following parameters in my VSCode's settings.json:
"editor.suggestFontSize": 20,
"editor.suggestLineHeight": 8,


You should check yours, and get rid of these lines, or change the values to fit your needs. (You should restart VSCode to apply changes)

To find your settings.json file, you can refer to VSCode User and Workspace Settings.
Be aware that these lines might be in your user settings and/or in your workspace settings.
Press Ctrl+Shift+P then select either:

Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)


For a complete list of settings, which can be changed, see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings. Do note that this list contains a short explanation for each setting.

@Luuk this is the same link as the one I already had in my answer, though maybe you were referring to samelink#_default-settings with the anchor on "default settings"?
